# How to solve data-frame join problem in r whith dplyr and tidyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data-frame with these characteristics:

```
Z Y X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 ... X30 

A n1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1      2

B n2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1      2

C n3 1 2 1 2 1 2 1      2

D n4 1 2 1 2 1 2 1      2

.
.
.
```

And I tried to associate the new column with z,y and x. Some like this:

```
Newcolumn            zyx
1                    x-y-z
```

I need a data-frame like this:

```
  colum1                  colum2  

1 A+n1+X1.headername      1

2 B+n2+X2.headernam       2

3 C+n3X3.headername       1

4 D+n4X4.headername       2

.                         .
.                         .
.                         .
```

I’m building this function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df_zy = df %>% pivot_longer(., cols = starts_with("X"), names_to = "Variables", 
values_to = "Value") %>%mutate(NewColumn = paste0(Z,"-",Y,"-",Variables)) %>% 
select(NewColumn, Value)
```

And I have some like this:

```
> df_zy
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  NewColumn Value
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 A-n1-X1       1
2 A-n1-X2       2
3 B-n2-X1       1
4 B-n2-X2       2
5 C-n3-X1       1
6 C-n3-X2       2
7 D-n4-X1       1
8 D-n4-X2       2
```

But the new column and value column not corresponde (e.g. X1 – 2, not X1 – 1). 
Does anybody have an option to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify your question? The code above seems to work correctly, I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Hi @Dave2e! The problem is the rows association with large data-frame, the two column have different pairs after association